# 'SQLSTATE[HY093], did I put a comma smewhere wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

I got my code mostly up an running. I seem to be constantly getting the same error over and over again. I think it's because I've put a comma somewhere wrong but I've no idea. Can anyone help me with this code?

```
<?php
    $db_server = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_password = "";
    $db_database = "meubelfabriek";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_database", $db_username, $db_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
        $naam = $_POST['fname'];
        $beschrijving = $_POST['desc'];
        $maat1 = $_POST['maat1'];
        $maat2 = $_POST['maat2'];
        $maat3 = $_POST['maat3'];
        $maat4 = $_POST['maat4'];
        $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
        $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
        if(substr($imageType,0,5)=="image")
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO producten ( naam, beschrijving, prijs, maat1, maat2, maat3, maat4, namen, image ) VALUES (  :naam, :beschrijving, :prijs,  :maat1, :maat2, :maat3, maat4,'$imageName', " . $conn->quote($imageData) . ")");
            $stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4));;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Oops, something went wrong!";    
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Provide complete error details

Comment: INSERT into query

Comment: maat4 replace it with :maat4 and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed an `:`:

```
:maat2, :maat3, maat4,'$imageName',  // There is a missing : before maat4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semi-colon in this line:

```
$stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>
$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4));; <--
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in If Statement

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO producten ( naam, beschrijving, prijs, maat1, maat2, maat3, maat4, namen, image ) VALUES (  :naam, :beschrijving, :prijs,  :maat1, :maat2, :maat3, maat4,'$imageName', " . $conn->quote($imageData) . ")");
        $stmt->execute(array(":naam"=>$naam, ":beschrijving"=>$beschrijving, ":prijs"=>$prijs, ":maat1"=>$maat1, ":maat2"=>$maat2, ":maat3"=>$maat3, ":maat4"=>$maat4));;
```

You add Double Quotes. Remove one .